# Populate a date by adding number of days with another input date field by using java script in php/html

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a transaction date field and due date field in my php-html page. I am trying to automatically populate the due date in the respective field by using Jaya script (for example: transaction date is 05-10-2014, my due date needs to be 18-11-2014 (05-10-2014 + 45) . I am not familiar with the java scripts. I am able to populate the same value from the transaction date field to due date field, but i have no idea how to add the 45 days with the transaction date.
Attaching the html code and java script.
I am using mysql DB.
Please help.
thanks in advance

```
Html code

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group col-sm-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-    calendar"></i></div>
<input id ="txndt" class="form-control" type="date" name ="purch_date" placeholder="Date of   transactions" required />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group col-sm-6">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Payment Due Date&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>   </div>
<input id ="duedt" class="form-control" type="text" name ="due_date"  readonly />
</div>
</div>

Java Script

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#txndt').keyup(function () {
$('#duedt').val(this.value);
});
</script>
```

entire script

```
    <?php
    require_once('auth.php');
    require_once('connection.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>DLBCC-Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>DLBCC-Purchases</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
.redborder {
    border:2px solid #f96145;
    border-radius:2px;
}
.colored {
    background-color: #F0EEEE;
}

.row {
    padding: 20px 0px;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">

               <a class="navbar-brand">DLB Credit Card transactions</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/Projects/dlbcc/home.php" class="scroll-link active" data-id="Home"><font color = "white"><b><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</b></font></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Purchases"><font color = "white"><b><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Add Purchases</b></font></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="refund"><font color = "white"><b><i class="fa fa-money"></i>&nbsp;Add Refund</b></font></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <font color = "white"><b> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Reports &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></b></font>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <!-- /.dropdown -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href= http://localhost/Projects/dlbcc/index.php><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
<form  name="purchase" method="post" action="dlbcc.php">
<div class = "container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <center> <h1><small>Input transaction details</small></h></center>
        </div>
    <br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      <input id ="txndt" class="form-control" type="date" name ="purch_date" placeholder="Date of transactions" required />
    </div>
</div>
<br/>   
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Amount &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-rupee"></i></div>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" name ="purch_amt" placeholder="Amount" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/> 
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Details&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-book"></i></div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name ="purch_dtls" placeholder="Details" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>    
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Payment Due Date&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></div>
      <input id ="duedt" class="form-control" type="date" name ="due_date" readonly  required/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
       <div class = "col-sm-4"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="submit_mult" type="submit">Save &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-save"></i></button></div>
</div>


</form>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <center><font color = "white">Copy Right &copy 2014-14: Prajith Ayril </font></center>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txndt').on('change', function(event) {
    var txndt = new Date(this.value);
    var duedt = txndt.addDays(45);

    $('#duedt').val(duedt.toString());
  });
});
</script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

latest code

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Add days</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function txnfn(){
                if(document.getElementById("txnType").value=='ccpurch'){
                    document.getElementById("duedtdiv").style.display="block";
                    document.getElementById("duedt").value = dat.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("duedtdiv").style.display="none";
                     }
                            }
             function   adddays()
                {
                    var dt = document.getElementById("txndt").value;
                    var dat = new Date(dt);
                    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 40);
                    document.getElementById("duedt").value = dat.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            Txn Type: <select name="txnType" id="txnType" onchange="txnfn();">
            <option value="ccpurch">Purchase</option>
            <option value="ccrefund">Refund</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        txn date:<input id ="txndt" type="date" name ="purch_date" onblur = "adddays();"/>
        <br/><br/>
                <div id="duedtdiv">
        due date:<input id ="duedt" type="date" name ="due_date"  readonly/>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [Add days to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/563442)

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txndt').on('change', function(event) {
    var txtdt = new Date(this.value);
    var duedt = txtdt.addDays(45);

    $('#duedt').val(duedt.toString());
  });
});
```

You'll only need to choose a way to format the date, here are some good options:

[how to format javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Comment: I have just copied the provided script and replace my existing script. Sorry, its not working (nothing is populating in the new field "duedt"). Whether anything i need to do additional other than replacing the script? I am just a beginner, that is why asking again. Please help.

Comment: Add your entire script so I can see what is the problem.

Comment: added entire script above. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I have managed my issue with the below 'code'. But still i have small issue. I have to input the date as 2014-10-09 (YYYY-MM-DD) and the output is getting like 20-oct-2014. is there any way to input the date as DD-MM-YYYY and the output also in same format. Please help.